# Get date range for multiple from/to dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code that I'am using to disable jquery ui datepicker date range in calendar. 
It selects every date in given range and echoes it. Problem is that it only echoes one from/to range but I need that for every from/to column:

```
$a = "select from_date,to_date from ads";

$rez = mysql_query($a) or die(mysql_error());
$c = mysql_num_rows($rez);

while ($re = mysql_fetch_array($rez))
{
    $from = $re["from_date"];
    $to = $re["to_date"];
}
$start=strtotime($from);
$s=date("Y-m-d",$start);
$diff = abs(strtotime($to) - strtotime($s)); 


$yrs   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
$mnth  = floor(($diff - $yrs * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
$days    = floor(($diff - $yrs * 365*60*60*24 - $mnth*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
$t=1;



$count = 0;
while($t <= $days){
if ($count++ > 0) echo ", ";
echo(json_encode($s));
$date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($s));
$s=date("Y-m-d", $date);
$t++;
}
```

Comment: `from` and `to` are both reserved words in `MYSQL`. So enclose it in backticks of your query.

Comment: its translated to understand better. i'll change it :)

Comment: use mysqli or pdo .Don't use mysql extension its depricated

Comment: i know, but i need it like this for now

Answer (score 0):

You are getting every column but you're overwriting each one and left with the last one selected.  You should build an array of your results and then loop over those.  I'm not sure 100% what you're going for, but something like this:

```
$result = array();
while ($re = mysql_fetch_array($rez))
{
    $from_date = $re["from_date"];
    $to_date = $re["to_date"];
    $start=strtotime($from);
    $s=date("Y-m-d",$start);
    $result[] = array($to_date, $s);
    ## Each element of $result is an array with two elements
    ## So $result[0][0] is the first to_date
}

## Now loop over each $result and process the to_date and $s value

foreach($result as $re){
    //echo $re[0] .' is this result\'s $to_date value';
    //echo $re[1] .' is this result\'s $s value';
    $to_date = $re[0];
    $s = $re[1];

    $diff = abs(strtotime($to_date) - strtotime($s)); 


    $yrs   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
    $mnth  = floor(($diff - $yrs * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
    $days    = floor(($diff - $yrs * 365*60*60*24 - $mnth*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
    $t=1;

    $count = 0;
    while($t <= $days){
      if ($count++ > 0) echo ", ";
      echo(json_encode($s));
      $date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($s));
      $s=date("Y-m-d", $date);
      $t++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'am getting some strange results. I need to echo every from/to date and all dates between them. This is what i get whe $s is echoed http://pastebin.com/chkPDLnE and this are actual dates with your echo http://pastebin.com/QSv3fkgw

Comment: the echos will only output the first and last date; I just fixed an error in my code above, where I changed `$to` to `$to_date`, i think it will do what you expect now...